# R Data Frame return value form column, not the index

Tags: r, dataframe, set

I have a problem with understanding how to print values instead of their index from data frame.

Here is my R code:

```
symmetric_difference <- function(x, ...) {
  single_vect <- c(x, ...)

  df <- as.data.frame(table(single_vect))

  lengthOfDf <- length(df$Freq)

  result <- c()

  for (i in 1:lengthOfDf) {
    if(df$Freq[i] %% 2 == 1){
      result <- c(result, df$single_vect[i])
    }
  }
  return(result)
}
```

What I'm trying to do is count all occurences of a given value, and then if the count is odd append the value to result vector. But instead, what is actually saved is the index from dataframe of this value.

When I print my whole `df` variable, or use `names(df)` the only column names I see are "single_vect" and "Freq".

I tried debugging this with `print()`, but when inside the `if` clause I print the value of `df$single_vect[i]` I get an actual value, not the index.

What am I doing wrong?

Test example:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
c <- c(3, 6, 9, 12)
symmetric_difference(a, b, c)
```

should return **1, 8, 9, 12**, but instead returns **1, 6, 7, 8**

Also, I know this code could be shrunk into one line, but I'm really trying to understand what's going on here.

Comment: This is a sidenote, but `result <- c()` should be `result <- numeric(lengthOfDf)` and `result <- c(result, df$single_vect[i])` should be `result[i] <- df$single_vect[i]`. The method you are using grows the vector which is inefficient in terms of memory use and speed.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I'm just pointing out there are no other column names to use, so when I actually type `df$single_vect[i]` I expect a value, not an index.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yes, append.

Comment: @lmo While this may actually speed up the script and use less memory, (which I'm not concerned about, as it won't be used for big calculations), this also has a side effect of adding unneccesary zeros to the results vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `single_vect` column of your table is coerced to a `factor`. One way of fixing this:

```
symmetric_difference <- function(x, ...) {
  single_vect <- c(x, ...)

  df <- as.data.frame(table(single_vect))
  df$single_vect <- as.numeric(levels(df$single_vect))

  lengthOfDf <- length(df$Freq)

  result <- c()

  for (i in 1:lengthOfDf) {
    if(df$Freq[i] %% 2 == 1){
      result <- c(result, df$single_vect[i])
    }
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: That's what I suspected, but had no idea on how to fix this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

your single_vect is vector. change it vack to numeric. 
use

`df$single_vect<-as.numeric(as.character(df$single_vect))`